# how to modify code to have variety number of nodes changes specific in DSDV in omnet?

Tags: omnet++

I do not know how to modify code in Destination sequenced distance vector protocol, how can I start to modify coding of the original coding in inetmanet?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy :)

- open file src/inet/routing/dsdv/Dsdv.cc in your favorite editor.
- make the changes.
- save the file
- rebuild INET

Comment: that means i need to modify in .cc file? not .ned ? make the changes means i can adding any coding from other sources?